# passing data between viewControllers late

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, null

1) Basically, data is passing through ViewControllers, but is getting late.
When nextViewController is executing code, some variables passed on

```
 override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {
    if (segue.identifier == "goto") ...
```

aren't set yet. Are still nil.

2) My second issue is related with first one: I am trying to pass data from selectedCell, so I am assigning a global variable on the delegate `didSelectItemAtIndexPath`. but when it reaches `prepareForSegue`, that variable I am going to pass is still nil.

Any help, please?

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: the thing is on 1) prepare for segue only assigns values when nextviewcontroller is already running and on 2) delegate is called only after prepare for segue. Any way to schedule this?

Comment: Hello Pedro, did you setup a segue from  tableviewCell to next ViewController in Storyboard or are you using performSegueWithIdentifier programmatically ?

Comment: Both. I did it on Storyboard to declare the segue and change its identifier and using performSegueWithIdentifier in order to pass some variables, is this wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You should either use the segue OR the table view delegate.

1. Setting Segue from TableviewCell to DetailViewController in Storyboard :-

Get the selected tableview cell in PrepareForSegue and access the appropriate data and pass onto next DetailVC.

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    //get the selected indexPath
    let selectedIndex = self.tableView.indexPathForCell(sender as UITableViewCell)
    var dataTobePassed = dataArray[selectedIndex.row]
        destination.data = dataTobePassed
}
```

-OR-

2. If there is segue between the two ViewControllers, then on tableview selection delegate method, you set the segue.

   func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
       self.performSegueWithIdentifier("showDetailVC", sender: indexPath);
   }

Then in your prepareForSegue method

```
 override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if (segue.identifier == "showDetailVC") {

        let path = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()!
        segue.destinationViewController.detail = self.detailForIndexPath(path)
      }
    }
```